# Field label not disappearing on input

Tags: html, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap

I recently started working on this website. The input field label is not disappearing when i click or enter values. The label still stays in the background even when the value is entered. It is a website developed using asp.net and bootstrap.

```
                    <div class="contact-form row">
                        <form runat="server" id="cntct_frm">
                            <ul>
                                <li class="text-field span3">
                                    <label id="name-contact-form">
                                        <span class="mainlabel">Name</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="input-prepend">
                                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-user"></i></span>
                                        <input class="required" type="text" name="yit_contact[name]" id="txtName" runat="server" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="msg-error">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clear">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="text-field span3">
                                    <label id="email-contact-form">
                                        <span class="mainlabel">Email</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="input-prepend">
                                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-envelope"></i></span>
                                        <input type="text" name="yit_contact[email]" id="txtEmail" runat="server" class="required email-validate"
                                            value="" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="msg-error">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clear">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="text-field span3">
                                    <label id="phone-contact-form">
                                        <span class="mainlabel">Phone</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="input-prepend">
                                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-phone"></i></span>
                                        <input type="text" name="yit_contact[phone]" maxlength="10" runat="server" id="txtMobile" />
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="msg-error">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clear">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="textarea-field span9">
                                    <label id="message-contact-form">
                                        <span class="mainlabel">Message</span>
                                    </label>
                                    <div class="input-prepend">
                                        <span class="add-on"><i class="icon-pencil"></i></span>
                                        <textarea name="yit_contact[message]" id="txtMessage" runat="server"
                                            class="required"></textarea>
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="msg-error">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="clear">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                                <li class="submit-button span9">
                                    <input type="text" name="yit_bot" id="yit_bot" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="yit_action" value="sendmail" id="yit_action" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="yit_referer" value="pages-contact.html" />
                                    <input type="hidden" name="id_form" value="3" />
                                    <asp:Button ID="Submit" name="yit_sendemail" class="sendmail alignright" runat="server"
                                        Text="Submit" OnClientClick="return validation()" OnClick="Submit_Click"></asp:Button>
                                    <div class="clear">
                                    </div>
                                </li>
                            </ul>
                        </form>
                    </div>
```

Comment: about which label you're talking? How you're hiding it.? Nothing is specified and we can't assume everything before answering your question.

Answer (score 0):

Remove row form first div that you showed.

```
<div class="contact-form">
// other codings
</div>
```

You haven't understood why we use **row**. please check http://getbootstrap.com/css/.

Comment: Removing 'row' did not fix the issue. It only messes up the display position of the fields.